# python sockets, trying to make a log in interaction betwen server and client

Tags: python, sockets, authentication

Hello so i have my server with a database (dictironay) and another passworddatabase

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *
host = ""
port = 8000
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket Created")
try:
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit()



database = {"name1" :{"hair" : "red", "size" : 1.50}}

password_database = {"name1": "1234",
                     "name2": "4321"}



def client_thread(conn): #threader client
    welcome = "Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter \n"
    conn.send(welcome.encode("UTF-8"))
    login(conn)
    while True:                # NOT IMPORTANT KEEP READING
        data = conn.recv(24)
        reply = data.decode("UTF-8")
        if reply == "1":
            menu1 = "Menu 1: Buy \n"
            conn.send(menu1.encode("UTF-8"))
        else:
            wrong = "wrong option \n"
            conn.send(wrong.encode("UTF-8"))



def login(conn):  #MY LOGIC PROBLEM IS HERE
    log = "Log in MENU: \n"
    logi = log.encode("UTF-8")
    conn.send(logi)
    us = "Username: \n"
    use = us.encode("UTF-8")
    conn.send(use)
    userr = conn.recv(24)
    user = userr.decode("UTF-8")
    pa = "Password: \n"
    pasw = pa.encode("UTF-8")
    conn.send(pasw)
    passr = conn.recv(24)
    passw = passr.decode("UTF-8")
    tries = 0
    while tries < 3:
        if user in passwordDictionary and passwordDictionary[user] == passw:
            print("Logged in")
            menu()
        else:
            print("Wrong Username Or Password \n")
            tries += 1
    print("You failed the login too many times, blocking you out")
    conn.close()



while 1: # NOT IMPORTANT
    conn, addr = serversocket.accept()
    print("Connected with " + addr[0] + ":" + str(addr[1]))
    start_new_thread(client_thread, (conn, ))
serversocket.close()
```

Whats working:
The server is working fine, i'm having troubles doing the login on the client side.

client.py ==> client DOESNT go into the `if data == Log in menu`
is there a better way to do this?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8000))
print("Connected")

datae = clientsocket.recv(24)
data = datae.decode("UTF-8")
clientsocket.send(datae)
while data != "!q":
    if data == "Log in MENU: \n":
        usere = input()
        user = usere.encode("UTF-8")
        clientsocket.send(user)
```

What would be the best way to create an log in interaction with the server?
the server has the usernames and passwords, i need to log in and then i need to edit the database depending on what user was chossen, but i'm having a hard time doing the algorithm

Comment: When you do `send('Log in MENU:\n')` then `send('Username: \n')` on one side, and `recv(24)` on the other side, you could end up getting anything from 1 to 24 of those bytes—so it could be just `L`, or 'Log in MENU:\nUsername: \n'`, or anything in between. Unless you happen to be running localhost on an machine not doing anything else, the odds of you getting exactly `Log in MENU:\n`, no more and no less, are pretty low. See [this blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for details.

Comment: In this case, [`makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) should be all you need to solve that problem. But you have a number of other problems as well, so just fixing one of them isn't going to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theres problems with the code you provided... however ill assume it actually works for you somehow and rather than copy paste you manually typed it

you are recieveing the first message here

```
datae = clientsocket.recv(24)
data = datae.decode("UTF-8") # GOT A MESSAGE
```

You then have the message `datae = b'Welcome to the server. '`

which does not match `"Log in MENU: \n"`, and `data != "!q"` so it goes back into your loop and checks if `data == "Log in MENU: \n"` it doesnt so it repeats ... but you never get the next message instead try something like this second message

```
data = ""
while data != "!q":
    if data == "Log in MENU: \n":
        usere = input()
        user = usere.encode("UTF-8")
        clientsocket.send(user)
    data = clientsocket.recv(24).decode("UTF-8")  # GET THE NEXT MESSAGE!
```

but even then you are going to have problems because your server continues to write so you will get something like `"Log in MENU: \nUsername"` or something .... basically you need to work out a better message passing scheme than `recv(24)`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Errors try using a header with something like 64 Bytes wich always is the first message send. This Header is then used to send the actual length of the following message to the server. For example:

```
def send_response(conn, msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    send_length = len(str(len(message)).encode(FORMAT))
    res_len = bytes(len(message)) + (b' ' * (HEADER - send_length))
    print(f"[SENDING MESSAGE] {msg}")

    conn.send(res_len)
    conn.send(response)
```